# SQL DB2: Using a WHERE subquery does not produce results

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I am using a subquery in the where clause for a DB2 table. the below produces no results:

```
SELECT b.people
FROM PLACES_TABLE A
JOIN PERSON_TABLE B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.AGR_ID IN (
  SELECT AGR_ID
  FROM AGREEMENT_TABLE
  WHERE AGR_CODE = 'AGR_CODE_01'
  WITH UR;
)
```

While the below does produce results:

```
SELECT b.people
FROM PLACES_TABLE A
JOIN PERSON_TABLE B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.AGR_ID IN (
  'AGR0001', 'AGR0002', 'AGR0003'  
)
```

In my first example, the 'where' subquery portion produces the correct ids when ran on its own (AGR0001, AGR0002, AGR0003). But together with the main query I get nothing back. The second example has the same ids yet returns a result.

Is there something that needs to be done in the where to make the subquery return char values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be the "With UR;" found in the below snippet?

Maybe that semi colon?

```
SELECT b.people
FROM PLACES_TABLE A
JOIN PERSON_TABLE B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.AGR_ID IN (
  SELECT AGR_ID
  FROM AGREEMENT_TABLE
  WHERE AGR_CODE = 'AGR_CODE_01'
  WITH UR;
)
```

Comment: Bingo! That "with ur;" was the issue.